# Make a div to fill the rest of the available screen height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this structure:

[image]

I would like to make **content2's min-height = height of screen - height of other divs**.

With the HTML/CSS below, the outcome is greater than the screen height. So How can I do what I wanted? The copyright part (footer) is inside the content2, so I want to make the content2's height to be exact in the screen.

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    background-color:#24373B;
    color: #fff;
}
#headerBG {
    min-width:980px;
    background-color:#000;
}
#header {
    width:980px;
}
#content1 {
    width:980px;
}
#content2 {
    width:960px;
    padding:10px;
    margin-top:30px;
    background-color:#355258;
    min-height:100hv;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="headerBG">
        <div id="header">header</div>
    </div>
    <div id="content1">content1</div>
    <div id="content2">content2</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is header and content1 fixed height?

Comment: No. It is not fixed. But i didnt put height:auto in css, i think it is default.

Comment: try `100vh` rather than `100hv`

Comment: still it is greater than the screen's height.

Comment: still it is greater than the screen's height.

Comment: Can you add your html?

Comment: @JonathonMilne is correct. `100vh` should work. [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhzrf5te/)

Comment: @RobertoNovelo Come on man! why would you need html for this? :D

Comment: The Uknown, It still greater than the screen's height.

Answer (score 1):

You are using 100hv instead of 100vh as min height. Fixed:

```
#content2{
    width:960px;
    padding:10px;
    margin-top:30px;
    background-color:#355258;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

But before you use vw or vh, you should define:

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use viewport units (`vw`, `vh`). You could simply do it with CSS `table` layout as follows. The height of the ***pink*** area will expand and fill out all the free space automatically.

http://jsfiddle.net/qtu89zhm/

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
}
.box {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.content-2 .cell, .content-2 .box {
    height: 100%;
}
.header .cell {
    background: gray;
}
.header .box {
    background: teal;
}
.content-1 .box {
    background: gold;
}
.content-2 .box {
    background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="row header">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="box">header</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row content-1">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="box">content1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row content-2">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="box">content2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly...

```css
body{
margin:0;
border:0;
background-color:#555555;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
}
#headerBG{
min-width:980px;
background-color:#AAAAAA;
  height:10%;
}
#header{
width:980px;
  height:100%;
  width:10%;
    
background-color:#FFF;
}
#content1{
width:980px;
  height:40%;
background-color:#000000;
  margin-left:5%;
  width:90%;
}
#content2{
margin-top:30px;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
  margin-left:5%;
  width:90%;
  height:50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="headerBG">
    <div id="header">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content1">
</div>
<div id="content2">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: It does not solve the problem. Thanks to your answer anyway :)

Comment: Should the content 2 be in the bottom of the screen? fixed height? This solves your original question I think.

Comment: I didn't see content2.

Comment: Missing a ; there, added some margins to make it look like your example.

Comment: The view is bigger than screen because content2 has a margin top of 30px